# How to properly import from a module in another sub-folder?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and attempting to build a basic REST API using Warp. However, I'm struggling to undestand the packages and modules structure in Rust.

For instance, here's my current project layout:

```
src/
├── main.rs
├── client/
│   └── ...
└── server/
    ├── handlers/
    │   ├── mod.rs
    │   └── item_handler.rs   <-- Where I want to use the struct Item
    ├── models/
    │   ├── mod.rs
    │   └── item.rs           <-- Where the struct Item is declared
    ├── routes/
    │   └── ...
    ├── api.rs
    └── mod.rs
```

In the `item_handler.rs` file, the approach I've taken to access the 'Item' struct from another module in a different folder was:

```
use super::super::models::item::Item;
//  │      └── /server
//  └── /handlers 

// Doing
//     use crate::server::models::item::Item
// didn't work
```

While this works, I'm uncertain if traversing the structure using nested super references is the recommended approach, considering that the project's module hierarchy could become extremely complex over time.

How is the more effective method for importing components in this case?

Comment: Using `mod.rs` files is, AFAIK, not recommended, but still supported for retrocompatibility. Instead, if you have like `models/mod.rs`, you could rename it to `models.rs` at the same level of the directory. This is much more practical if you are editing several of these files at once, otherwise you'll just have a bunch of `mod.rs` open tab and you won't know who's who.

Comment: @jthulhu This is debated in the Rust community. Some (including me) prefer the `mod.rs` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right `mod` declarations in your mod.rs files?

```rust
// server/mod.rs

pub mod handlers;  // all of these could be pub(crate) instead
pub mod models;
```

```rust
// server/handlers/mod.rs

pub mod item_handler;
```

```rust
// server/models/mod.rs

pub mod item;
```

If you've done that, your `use crate::server::models::item::Item` will work.

Comment: My `mod.rs`'s files are exactly as you declared, but I still got the error `error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `server` in the crate root`

Comment: @G.Bittencourt where is `mod server`? if there is one?

Comment: @kmdreko in `src/main.rs`, as `pub mod server;`

Comment: It sounds like everything is as it should be, unless you have a `#[path = ...]` attribute somewhere in your hierarchy mucking things up. If `super::super` works for you then you can obviously use it, the distinction of when to use a relative import vs an absolute import is largely up to preference.